# Multiplexing common anode 7 segments using only 2 shift register, darlington array, and transistor

Tags: transistors, multiplexer, shift-register, 7segmentdisplay, uln2003

I'm trying to multiplex up to 8 digit common anode 7 segment display using only 2 shift registers chained together in series driven by arduino. So it would need only 3 pins (trying to save up pins here) for clock, latch, and data.
The display requires larger power so i separate the power from arduino using ULN2003 Darlington array on cathode (segment) side. And using pnp transistors for anode (digit) side. Which both sides are driven by shift register.

What i expect is i can just use 3 pins of arduino to send 2 byte data. First byte for segment, and second byte for digits. And using different power source for the display.

My question is, is this circuit correct? Will it works?
If it doesn't, then please tell how to make it works?

Here's my rough schematic, i only draw 2 digits here for example.
EDIT: i'm using 2 power supply. 5v for arduino, 12v for display. The ground of both supply are connected (common).
[image: schematic]

Comment: No, it won't work. There is no connection from the shift registers to the Arduino, and no connections to power for several components. If you want to provide a **rough** schematic then you must ask a **specific question** that can be answered using only the information provided. Otherwise, take the time to draw a complete schematic.

Comment: i've drawn the complete schematic. there are 2 power supply used, 5v for arduino and 12v for display. Please review the question.

Comment: Please provide links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the LED displays, the PNP transistors, the Darlington array, and the shift register. Please explain the purpose of the 7 resistors and show how you calculated their value. Please discuss your design decisions regarding the current passing through the LEDs. Please discuss how your code will multiplex the displays and what will happen if the code hangs and one display is left on continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with the driver circuit. The high side drivers are all wrong, they **will** fry everything connected to the +5V supply (including the Arduino) tout suit. Please review other answers for how to drive LEDs and how to design high side drivers. If you need to use the 12V supply you can use another 2003 or some NPN transistors (in addition to the PNP transistors) and some resistors to limit the base currents.

You **need** resistors in series with the segment lines (7 of them) to limit the peak LED currents. Where you have resistors (at the input of the 2003) you don't need them.

The basic concept of 16 bits of daisy-chained shift registers is sound.

Comment: @gema: See [High-side driver fail](http://lednique.com/gpio-high-side-driver-fail/) for some explanation on Spehro's first point. The ULN2003 has the base resistors built-in. They're clearly shown in the datasheet.

Comment: Yes! Thanks Sphero. "Level translator" is the keyword i need right now. Using npn and pnp transistor. And thanks to Transistor's link i somehow understand how to do it. The resistors part is my mistake, i drew the schematic in haste.